# How can I have a type checker in python for nested lists and basic types?

Tags: python, python-2.6

What is the standard approach if I need to write a type validator for basic types which would include nested lists.

i.e. if I am given a value `a` and a string `list<list<int>>`, how can I check that `a` is effectively a `list` of `list` of `int`s ?

Is there a Pythonic approach to this ?

Note: I know that Python is about duck typing, it is just that in this case I need to have some validation as the data will be passed to another system.

Comment: Can you have deep nesting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `isinstance` to check the type of something

```
def is_list_of_list_of_int(a):
    return isinstance(a, list) and isinstance(a[0], list) and isinstance(a[0][0], int)

>>> is_list_of_list_of_int([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]])
True
>>> is_list_of_list_of_int(5)
False
```

The other methodology is "it is better to ask forgiveness than permission"

```
def get_value_safe(a, i, j):
    try:
        return a[i][j]
    except TypeError:
        print('not a list of list')
        return None

>>> get_value_safe([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]], 1, 2)
4
>>> get_value_safe([1,2,3], 1, 2)
not a list of list
```

Comment: I was looking more for something that would do the recursive check on all elements, no matter the number of concatenations. I am able to write it but I did not want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @BlueTrin So are you asking for a function that determines if you have an arbitrary nested sequence of a given type?

Answer (score 1):

I must admit, this is the first time I've touched recursion in *ages*, but I think the only way to check every item of your object is by recursion. Or dynamic programming, and I don't like dynamic programming :P

I absolutely hate parsing strings, so I'm opting to just pass in types instead.

```
def typecheck(obj, *args):
    if isinstance(obj, args[0]):
        if len(args) == 1: # last one to check. Base case.
            return True
        if hasattr(args[0], "__iter__"): 
            #in other words, am I an iterator?
            for i in obj:
                if not typecheck(i, *args[1:]):
                    return False
            return True
     else: 
        return False

In [23]: typecheck([[3,3, "a"]],list, list, int)
Out[23]: False

In [24]: typecheck([[3,3]],list, list, int)
Out[24]: True
```

Should be pretty trivial to add `logging` to this, for a variant that just tells you exactly where your object is the wrong type

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to check lists and basic types, the first part of the answer is parsing the type spec to a list of types (going from parent to child):

```
import __builtin__
def parse_spec(str_spec):
    return [getattr(__builtin__, x) for x in str_spec.rstrip('>').split('<')]
```

The second part is validating a specified value conforms to the spec:

```
def validate(value, spec):
    for t in spec:
        if not isinstance(value, t):
            return False
        try:
            value = value[0]
        except TypeError:
            pass
    return True
```

So, you can combine these functions as follows:

```
>>> validate([10], parse_spec('list<int>'))
True
>>> validate([10], parse_spec('int'))
False
>>> validate([['something']], parse_spec('list<list<str>>'))
True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that all your elements are of a certain type with arbitrary levels of nesting I would use recursion:

```
from collections import Iterable


def is_list_or_int(l):
    if not isinstance(l, (list, int)):
        return False
    if isinstance(l, Iterable):
        for ele in l:
            if not is_list_or_int(ele):
                return False
    return True
```

Output:

```
In [9]: is_list_or_int([1, [2, [[["4"], 3, 4]]],2, 3, 4])
Out[9]: False

In [10]: is_list_or_int([1, [2, [[[4], 3, 4]]],2, 3, 4])
Out[10]: True
```